# Kairosdb error metric[0](name=abcd).tag[xyz].value may not be empty

Tags: cassandra, opentsdb, kairosdb

I am inserting data in kairosdb using the command: [reference](https://code.google.com/p/kairosdb/wiki/ImportExport)

> bin/kairosdb.sh import -f export.txt

but in the kairosdb.log file I am getting following error:

```
08-10|13:54:33.443 [main] INFO  [Main.java:267] -      KairosDB service started
08-10|13:54:33.443 [main] INFO  [Main.java:268] - ------------------------------------------
08-10|14:00:38.236 [main] INFO  [TelnetServerModule.java:42] - Configuring module TelnetServerModule
08-10|14:00:39.259 [main] INFO  [CassandraHostRetryService.java:48] - Downed Host Retry service started with queue size -1 and retry delay 10s
08-10|14:00:39.357 [main] INFO  [JmxMonitor.java:52] - Registering JMX me.prettyprint.cassandra.service_kairosdb-cluster:ServiceType=hector,MonitorType=hector
08-10|14:00:39.734 [main] ERROR [Main.java:345] - metric[0](name=meterreadings).tag[building_type].value may not be empty.
08-10|14:00:40.023 [main] ERROR [Main.java:345] - metric[0](name=meterreadings).tag[building_type].value may not be empty.
08-10|14:00:40.216 [main] ERROR [Main.java:345] - metric[0](name=meterreadings).tag[building_type].value may not be empty.
08-10|14:00:40.295 [main] ERROR [Main.java:345] - metric[0](name=meterreadings).tag[building_type].value may not be empty.
08-10|14:00:40.391 [main] ERROR [Main.java:345] - metric[0](name=meterreadings).tag[building_type].value may not be empty.
08-10|14:00:40.439 [main] ERROR [Main.java:345] - metric[0](name=meterreadings).tag[building_type].value may not be empty.
```

My export.txt file is:

```
administrator@administrator-IdeaCentre-Q190:~/Abharthan/kairosdb$ head -10 export.txt
{"name": "meterreadings", "timestamp":"1359695700","tags": {"Building_id":"1","building_type":"ElementarySchool","meter_type":"temperature","unit":"F"},"value":"34.85"}
{"name": "meterreadings", "timestamp":"1359695700","tags": {"Building_id":"2","building_type":"Park","meter_type":"temperature","unit":"F"},"value":"0"}
{"name": "meterreadings", "timestamp":"1359695700","tags": {"Building_id":"3","building_type":"Industrial","meter_type":"temperature","unit":"F"},"value":"0.07"}
{"name": "meterreadings", "timestamp":"1359695700","tags": {"Building_id":"4","building_type":"RecreationCenter","meter_type":"temperature","unit":"F"},"value":"0"}
{"name": "meterreadings", "timestamp":"1359695700","tags": {"Building_id":"5","building_type":"Park","meter_type":"temperature","unit":"F"},"value":"2.2"}
{"name": "meterreadings", "timestamp":"1359695700","tags": {"Building_id":"6","building_type":"CommunityCenter","meter_type":"temperature","unit":"F"},"value":"31.41"}
{"name": "meterreadings", "timestamp":"1359695700","tags": {"Building_id":"7","building_type":"Office","meter_type":"temperature","unit":"F"},"value":"0"}
{"name": "meterreadings", "timestamp":"1359695700","tags": {"Building_id":"8","building_type":"ElementarySchool","meter_type":"temperature","unit":"F"},"value":"10.88"}
{"name": "meterreadings", "timestamp":"1359695700","tags": {"Building_id":"9","building_type":"ElementarySchool","meter_type":"temperature","unit":"F"},"value":"42.27"}
{"name": "meterreadings", "timestamp":"1359695700","tags": {"Building_id":"10","building_type":"ElementarySchool","meter_type":"temperature","unit":"F"},"value":"10.14"}
```

Please suggest how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually the problem you describe comes from tags being provided with no associated value. TIt looks like you have values after the 10 first lines with empty value for building_type (look for `"building_type":""` or similar).

By looking at your JSON I see several unrelated possible problems :

- Your timestamp seems to be in Unix seconds - it should be in milliseconds (that could work with Telnet API because of OpenTSDB compatibility, but KairosDB expects milliseconds)
- Your timestamp  is always the same (thus you updating the same sample and again)
- Your value is a String (while you'd probably like to use a long or a float), it may work but I don't recommend proceeding this way

Comment: Yes some of the data were null. Thanks..!!